# How can I convert string to bytes in Python, like node js

Tags: python, hex, byte

I used binary data with Buffer in node js like this.

```
<Buffer 01 05 01 4c 61 60>
```

How could I use that in Python?

I tried to make that but... the result was

```
    a = a.to_bytes(2,'big')
    b = b.to_bytes(1, 'big')
    result = a + b + str.encode(c)
```

> > b"\x01\x05\x01{'Lang': 'En'}"

or

```
codecs.encode(result,'hex')
```

> > b"0105014c6160"

1. Why they show me the escape character? How could I remove that?
2. the first one and last one is same data?

Comment: It *is* the binary data; the escape characters let it show (some of) the bytes as readable text.  What would it mean to “be in hex”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the title and your wording it sounds like you are looking for something similar to node.js [Buffer.from](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding), which returns a mutable array like binary data.

Python has the [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#func-bytearray) function which allows you to mutate the data

```
>>> a = bytearray('hello, world!', encoding='utf8')
>>> a[0]
104
>>> a[0] = 105
>>> x
bytearray(b'iello, world!')
```

If you don't need mutability you can just encode the string to bytes `'hello, world!'.encode('utf8')` (assuming the encoding you are working with is utf8).

You can override the way it's represented like so.

```
>>> class MyBytes(bytes):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return '<Bytes {}>'.format(' '.join([hex(i) for i in self]))
...
>>> MyBytes('hello', encoding='utf8')
<Bytes 0x68 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f>
```

Comment: The question didn’t say anything about converting from `str` to `bytes` (or `bytearray`), did it?

Comment: The title is literally "How can I convert string to bytes in Python, like node js". I guess the more pythonic answer would be `"somestr".encode(someencoding)`.

Comment: True, but the question body seems to emphasize the “like Node.js” (and to illustrate confusion about representations).

Comment: You're right, I'll update my answer to reflect my assumptions.